# Forest: Exclude subtree from packing algorithm

Tags: forest

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={}
[A
 [B 
  [C ]
  [C ]
 ]
  [1[2][3]]
 [B
  [C ] 
  [C ] 
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Is it possible to

ignore the nodes containing numbers to draw the first part of the tree and then append the "subtree" containing the numbers to the root.

in a way that the output is like this:

[image: example2]

**EDIT**
My goal is to put a small 'unimportant' tree into a bigger one. I was only able to make the 'unimportant' tree small enough by changing the y coordinates before the tree is drawn. But this leaves some emty space in the tree:

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
    unimportant/.style={
        fit=rectangle,
        for tree={
            delay={content/.process={Ow {content}{\tiny ##1}}},
        },
        before drawing tree={
            for tree={
                delay={
                    inner sep=2pt,
                    typeset node,
                    y+/.process={Ow+n {level}{##1*20}},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={}
[A
 [B 
  [C [D][D]] 
  [C [D][D]]
 ]
  [1, unimportant[2[3][4]]]
 [B
  [C [D][D]] 
  [C [D][D]] 
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: example3]

Whereas I want to achieve this:[image]

Comment: Why do you want that overlapping of 2 and C / 3 and C? Or do you want to make a cycle in a tree?

Comment: @dexteritas I want to put a "tiny" tree into a bigger tree (see above).

Comment: I'd add the sub-tree after the main tree is packed.

Comment: @cfr how would you achieve that? It does not seem to be possible using`insert after={[1[2[3][4]]]}`.

Comment: @Imperaton No. I'd remove the sub-tree while the rest is packed and the xy values are computed. Then put it back. You could delay it and use something like `insert after`. It was just the `remove` and replace strategy I had in mind. That way the sub-tree is specified but it isn't part of the tree when the tree is packed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't mind naming the node, it is relatively easy. It is perfectly possible otherwise, but a bit less straightforward.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  unimportant/.style={
    name=#1,
    for tree={
      font=\tiny,
    },
    before packing={pack, remove},
    !u.before drawing tree={
      append=#1,
      delay={
        for nodewalk={name=#1}{for tree={l*=.5, inner sep=2pt, delay=compute xy, delay n=2{y-/.option=l}}},
      }
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={}
  [A
   [B
    [C [D][D]]
    [C [D][D]]
   ]
    [1, unimportant=this one [2[3][4]]]
   [B
    [C [D][D]]
    [C [D][D]]
   ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: removing and reintegrating sub-tree]

Comment: Your `forest`-fu always impresses me. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn The manipulation of `y` feels a bit hacksh. But I couldn't find another way.

Answer (score 0):

This question interests me. Here is my try to draw this tree using the [`istgame`](http://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
% bigger tree
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none}}
\xtdistance{12mm}{40mm}
\istrooto(0){A} \istb \istb \endist
\foreach \n in {1,2}
{
\xtdistance{12mm}{20mm}
\istrooto(B\n)(0-\n){B} \istb \istb \endist
\xtdistance{12mm}{10mm}
\istrooto()(B\n-1){C} \istb{}{\mbox{D}} \istb{}{\mbox{D}} \endist
\istrooto()(B\n-2){C} \istb{}{\mbox{D}} \istb{}{\mbox{D}} \endist
}
% tiny tree
\begin{scope}[font=\scriptsize]
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1.5pt}}
\xtdistance{3mm}{4mm}
\istrooto(00)([yshift=-2mm]0)[plain node] \istb \endist
\istrooto(1)(00-1){1} \istb<level distance=4mm> \endist
\istrooto(2)(1-1){2} \istb{}{3\ }[below,yshift=3pt] \istb{}{\ 4}[below,yshift=3pt] \endist
\end{scope}
\end{istgame}
\end{document}
```